# Tuple index out of range, when visulaizing CNN filters

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using CNN for my binary image classification task. I want to see filters of convolution layer using following code in Keras:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
def nice_imshow(ax, data, vmin=None, vmax=None, cmap=None):
    """Wrapper around pl.imshow"""
    if cmap is None:
        cmap = cm.jet
    if vmin is None:
        vmin = data.min()
    if vmax is None:
        vmax = data.max()
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
    im = ax.imshow(data, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    pl.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
    pl.savefig("/home/nd/Results/filter--{}".format(q) + '.jpg')

import numpy.ma as ma
def make_mosaic(imgs, nrows, ncols, border=1):
    """
    Given a set of images with all the same shape, makes a
    mosaic with nrows and ncols
    """
    nimgs = imgs.shape[0]
    imshape = imgs.shape[1:]

    mosaic = ma.masked_all((nrows * imshape[0] + (nrows - 1) * border,
                            ncols * imshape[1] + (ncols - 1) * border),
                            dtype=np.float32)

    paddedh = imshape[0] + border
    paddedw = imshape[1] + border
    for i in range(nimgs):
        row = int(np.floor(i / ncols))
        col = i % ncols

        mosaic[row * paddedh:row * paddedh + imshape[0],
               col * paddedw:col * paddedw + imshape[1]] = imgs[i]
    return mosaic


# Visualize weights
filternumber=[1]
for q in filternumber:
    W=model.layers[q].get_weights()[0][:,:,0,:]
    W=np.swapaxes(W,0,2)
    W = np.squeeze(W)
    print("W shape : ", W.shape)
    pl.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
    pl.title('conv1 weights')
    nice_imshow(pl.gca(), make_mosaic(W, 16, 16), cmap=cm.binary)
```

and getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-35-a2febeda1dfc>", line 51, in <module>
    nice_imshow(pl.gca(), make_mosaic(W, 16, 16), cmap=cm.binary)

  File "<ipython-input-35-a2febeda1dfc>", line 26, in make_mosaic
    mosaic = ma.masked_all((nrows * imshape[0] + (nrows - 1) * border,

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

My model summary is following:

## Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to

input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 30, 30, 1)    0

---

conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 30, 30, 64)   128         input_1[0][0]

---

conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, 30, 30, 64)   128         input_1[0][0]

---

max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 30, 30, 1)    0           input_1[0][0]

---

conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 30, 30, 64)   36928       conv2d_1[0][0]

---

conv2d_4 (Conv2D)               (None, 30, 30, 64)   102464      conv2d_3[0][0]

---

conv2d_5 (Conv2D)               (None, 30, 30, 64)   128         max_pooling2d_1[0][0]

---

concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 30, 30, 192)  0           conv2d_2[0][0]
                                                                 conv2d_4[0][0]
                                                                 conv2d_5[0][0]

---

flatten_1 (Flatten)             (None, 172800)       0           concatenate_1[0][0]

---

dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 2)            345602      flatten_1[0][0]

How to solve problem. My img size is 30*30.

Comment: What is the result of `print("W shape : ", W.shape)`?

Comment: W shape :  (64,)

Comment: You are passing `W` into the function as `imgs` with a shape of `W shape : (64,)`. This means the line `imshape = imgs.shape[1:]` will produce `()` — an empty tuple.

Comment: Ok sir i understand, please suggest me the modification in code.

Comment: I have commented `W = np.squeeze(W)` layer and getting results, for but `concatenate` filters i am not getting results.